# Hello, someone help to resolve this error. I getting this when ever I am building an app

Tags: asp.net

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Reflection.Assembly._GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +0
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +42
   System.Web.UI.Util.GetTypeFromAssemblies(ICollection assemblies, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase) +145
   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.GetType(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnError) +73
   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessInheritsAttribute(String baseTypeName, String codeFileBaseTypeName, String src, Assembly assembly) +111
   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.PostProcessMainDirectiveAttributes(IDictionary parseData) +279

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the application trust level in your web.config

Add something like this to your system.web section:

```
<system.web>
  <securityPolicy>
    <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
  </securityPolicy>
</system.web>
```

If it works, decrease your trustLevel to High, then to Medium, then to Low to see which trust level is sufficient for your application.

Comment: Actually I found the Issue, the project was created in an network not on my local. Thanks for your time to have look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the Issue, the project was created in an network not on my local. Thanks for your time to have look into this